# Salt and set new password

Tags: php

I am trying to use md5 and salt the password so for example the account name and `stackoverflow` md5 and salted looks like

`OÜ ª€ÉØ¸ÖÙõà;~\` when it is done correctly, but I am getting what looks to be just the md5, its like its not salting the account name and password. So when I do the md5 hash of the account name and `jade` it looks like `0xea606b4cae6ae9a68a5da45d57c3309d` but what I'm really looking for is

```
ê`kL®jé¦Š]¤]WÃ0
```

I couldn't close that in `backticks` as it has one after the `e`.

Here is a snippet of the code I am using for an example.

```
    $new = isset($_POST['new']) ? $_POST['new'] : '';
    $old = isset($_POST['old']) ? $_POST['old'] : '';
    $con = isset($_POST['con']) ? $_POST['con'] : '';
    $this->view->usr = mysql_real_escape_string(StrToLower(Trim($this->view->usr)));
    $new = mysql_real_escape_string(StrToLower(Trim($new)));

    $Salt = $this->view->name.$new;
    $Salt = md5($Salt);
    $Salt = "0x".$Salt; //Salts the password in md5.

    //$this->view->salt = $this->view->name.$new;
    //$this->view->salt = md5($this->view->salt);
    //$this->view->salt = "0x".$this->view->salt; //Salts the password in md5.
    $this->view->msg = "";
    $this->view->err = false;

    if($old != $this->view->pss){
        $this->view->msg = "Old Password is Incorrect";
    }elseif($new == ""){
        $this->view->msg = "New Password is Empty";
    }elseif($con != $new){
        $this->view->msg = "Please Confirm Password Correctly";
    }else{
        $arr = array(":idnumber" => $new, ":passwd" => $Salt);
        $this->database->DBSet($arr,'users',$whr = 'WHERE ID = '.$this->view->usr);
        $this->view->msg = "Password is Successfully Changed";
        $this->view->err = true;
    }
```

---

I do have a script that works and returns what i am looking for, but it uses the following procedure from the database so i have to do `call changepasswd('$Login', $Salt)`

```
BEGIN
 START TRANSACTION;
  UPDATE users SET passwd = passwd1 WHERE name = name1;
 COMMIT;
END
```

I did notice that `$Salt` is outside of `'single quotes'`, is there a way to do that with the following snippet?

`$arr = array(":idnumber" => $new, ":passwd" => $Salt);`

I thought I would beable to do the same thing with this PDO Update function

```
// Update
    function DBSet($arr,$tbl,$whr = ''){
        $stmt = array();
        foreach($arr as $fld => $val){
            $stmt[] =  str_replace(":","",$fld)." = ".$fld;
        }
        $stm =  implode(",",$stmt);
        $sql =  self::UPDATE.$tbl." SET ".$stm.' '.$whr;
        $sth =  $this->prepare($sql, array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_FWDONLY));
        $sth->execute($arr);
    }
```

Comment: If you're using MD5, you've already lost this game. MD5 is not suitable for securely hashing passwords.

Comment: It is for a private server, that's how the game logs somebody in.

Comment: All hashed password databases are private, you store the hash so that when somebody *breaks into* your private server, they can't see plain-text passwords. It doesn't matter how "private" your server is, if you're trying to hash passwords and you're using MD5, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: your not understanding me, it's for a game that requires it to be hashed with MD5 and salted.

Comment: So this is for someone else's game (in which case they have mandated the use of MD5?) as opposed to your own game?

Comment: yes, i just run a private server of it.

Comment: If you are saying you expect MD5 (salted or not) to produce "OÜ ª€ÉØ¸ÖÙõà;~\", you are mistaken on how MD5 and salting works. It is likely your "correct" method uses some other step or algorithm all together. In the future, take a look at this: https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm

Comment: I edited my original post

Answer (score -1):

So, you want to hash a string and it would produce `êkL®jé¦Š]¤]WÃ0`?
MD5 couldn't do that, it always return 32 characters..

Use another encrypt algorithm to produce cipher string like that.